# unity3d - help needed to rotate a cube diagonally

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning to use Unity3d and I want to rotate a cube diagonally so that it appears to be spinning diagonally when I press the left arrow key + q or right arrow key + w. Can anyone assist me with my query?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
void Update () 
{
   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) //move forward
      transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) //move backward
      transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) //turn left
      transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) //turn right
      transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean diagonally as in on 2 different axis?

Comment: do you mean that the `transform.Rotate`'s that you do, aren't working correctly? Or something else?

Comment: If I press the left arrow key and the q key together, I want the cube to spin toward the top left hand corner. I've tried the rotate function: transform.Rotate(rotateAmount ===>this is a public vec3 variable * Time.deltaTime), but this doesn't seem to work when pressing both keys at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) { //turn diagonally to the left
transform.Rotate(new Vector3 (moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) { //turn diagonally to the right
transform.Rotate(new Vector3 (moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, -moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

if it's rotating to the wrong direction, replace -moveSpeed with moveSpeed and moveSpeed with -moveSpeed, I hope this works (untested)

Comment: accept the answer if it works, if it doesn't tell me what's happenning

Comment: I had to reverse movespeed variables as you suggested - now working as it should

Comment: Glad to help, I know I commited a mistake in the code, it was simple to fix though, I already edited it anyway

Comment: oh I only noticed now you want to rotate it while pressing like left and q, not only q, so change the if to statement to if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)), but you probably already know that